# M/D/c queue with different service times

Tags: queueing-theory

In formulas on M/D/c queue it is assumed that service time is the same for all servers.
Are there formulas for the case when service times differ between servers (in general case there would be as many service times as there are servers) ?
For example there is a group of servers, all providing the same service, but servers capabilities differ, so the service time although constant is not the same among the servers.

I am interested in response time distribution primarily.

Thanks in advance
Ilja

Comment: Could you please add some details?

Comment: You *can* set up the balance equations for such a case, but the formulas that result are guaranteed to be a horrible mess unless you are extremely lucky with the service times.

Comment: What particular performance metrics are you interested in? The steady state distribution, response time distribution, waiting time distribution, mean number of customers in the system, server utilization, mean response/waiting time. What kind of answer are you interested in? Bear in mind what solutions look like for the regular M/D/c queue (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/D/c_queue) so you won't find simpler expressions.

Comment: This system is underspecified: Are the tasks non-preemptive?  What is the allocation discipline?  The simplest realization I can think of has preemptive tasks with each task going and/or transitioning to the fastest available server, but even that seems pretty complicated.  Unless there's some interesting symmetry, the state space seems like it would be continuous and multi-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Your system description is still slightly vague, is it such that it could be described by the $c+1$ dimensional vector where the first $c$ components describe the remaining service of the job at each of the service nodes and the final element the number of queueing jobs awaiting service?

Suppose there is one job queueing and a server becomes available, but that if the job waited a while a faster server would become available and it would finish earlier. What does the job do in this situation? As you have heterogeneous servers you need to carefully define the system dynamics as there are complications that do  not arise in the standard M/D/$c$ model.

You may find simulation is the easiest way to numerical values for a particular situation, if this is what you seek.

Comment: Yes Gareth, that is the system I have in mind. For the job in queue, I assume FIFO - the first server that appears, services the job. I thought someone probably already worked on such a system.